# Master to Master replication in Redis Sentinel

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-sentinel

We are establishing a Redis Sentinel cluster in two zones. Each zone will have a master node with two slave nodes. We are looking for master-to-master replication between these zones (not in real time though).

According to my understanding, Redis Enterprise does provide this feature. But do we have anything for Redis sentinel configuration?

I came across some answers where [Dynomite](http://www.dynomitedb.com/) was mentioned as an option, but it appears that the project is no longer active.

We couldn't find much information on this. Is a Redis Sentinel-compatible solution available for this?

Answer (score 0):

I was in exact same situation and we had  to modify how we put data to redis and have it duplicated in both cluster

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).